# Dificuldade para consultar em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Primeiramente eu estou começando agora a mexer com mySQL sou muito leigo no assunto ainda

Eu tenho uma tabela que se chama `products_search_items` e nessa tabela tem 2 colunas a `product_i"` e a `search_item_id`

eu precisava por exemplo, pegar todos os `product_id` que tenha um `search_item_id` de valor 20 e 14

com essa query que eu fiz eu consigo pegar todos os `search_item_id` de valor 20 e mostrar os `product_id` com esse `search_item_id`

```
SELECT id.product_id FROM products_search_items AS id
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = id.product_id 
WHERE search_item_id = 20
```

Por exemplo aqui nessa table

```
# product_id search_item_id
    26              14
    26              20
    29              29
    29              20
    44              31
```

essa query me retornaria isso :

```
# product_id
    26      
    29
```

mas eu preciso que ela retorne só os `product_id` que tenham os `search_item_id` de valor 20 e 14. Precisa ter necesseariamente os dois `search_item_id`. Se, por exemplo, houver apenas um deles, então o product_id não pode se retornado.

Portanto, no *dataset* acima apresentado teria que retornar algo como isso:

```
# product_id
    26
```

Comment: O que eu não entendi foi o seguinte: Se você quer obter os product_id a partir dos search_item_id que sejam (20,14), isso implica em retornar os seguintes product_id: (26,29). Porque você excluiu o product_id 29 do resultado esperado?

Comment: então eu queria que retornasse só os product_id que tenha o search_item_id (20,14) o product_id 29 não tem um search_item_id 14, eu queria que retornasse somente o product_id que tivesse o search_item_id(20,14), tipo tem 2 product_id 26, um com search_item_id 20 e outro com 14, eu queria que retornasse só o product_id que tivesse esses 2 search_item_id, não sei se é possível, e também sou meio péssimo para explicar rs,

Comment: Entendi. Você só deseja obter os product_id que tenham, necessariamente, os search_item_id 14 e 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que você precisa:

```
select product_id from products_search_items
where search_item_id in (14,20) 
group by product_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Esse SQL retornará apenas os product_id que tenham o count(*) = 2, ou seja, apenas aqueles que tenham os search_item_id = 14 ou search_item_id = 20.

No exemplo da pergunta, retornará apenas o product_id = 26

Answer (score 5):

Basta usar o operador `IN` na query:

```
SELECT psi.product_id FROM products_search_items AS psi
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = psi.product_id 
WHERE search_item_id IN (20,14)
```

O resultado obtido:

```
product_id
26
26
29
```

Mudei também o Alias que você deu na tabela `products_search_items` de `id` para `psi`, se não fica confusa a *query*.

[Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-os-operadores-like-in-e-between-no-oracle/24687) você pode aprender mais a respeito do comando `IN`.